# solving the non linear ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the equation for $$\frac{\partial^{2}\psi(\sqrt{g} y)}{\partial y^{2}}=(\frac{sin^{2}(\sqrt{g}y)}{g}-\frac{2E}{\omega})\psi(\sqrt{g}y)$$.//
$\psi$ is a function of y, so now I have no clue to start this. I know the range of $\sqrt {g}y$ from $\frac{-\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and I have the boundary conditions given as $$\psi(-\frac{\pi}{2})=0$$ $$\psi(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$$. I need a guidance to solve it I know the values of $$\frac{E}{\omega}$$ and other parameters. I haven't solved any of such equation.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MathieuFunction.html

Comment: I know this can be converted into mathiu's equations. I want to solve it by hand to see how it works. Is it possible anyway?